# Как правильно организовать методы класса и методы экземпляра

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы, методы

Только начал вникать в саму концепцию ООП. Туплю на понятийном уровне:
Понимаю, что есть методы, имеющие смысл применительно к конкретному экземпляру класса (методы экземпляра) и методы "отстраненные", внешние: им "без разницы", каким экземпляром оперировать (по видимому, это методы класса).

Что делать, если эти методы желательно и назвать синонимично, и делать они должны (почти или точно) одно и то же, разница должна быть лишь в способе вызова.

Как бы вы организовали следующий класс:

```
class Person:

    isMarriedTo = None

    # метод экземпляра
    def marry(self, other):
        """Выбранный Экземпляр (сам) женится на другом экземпляре"""
        print(f'{self} married {other}')     # специфичный код
        hypotetic_common_method(self, other) # вызов общего кода

# внешний по отношению к экземплярам метод.
# здесь помещен в модуль вне класса, но хотелось бы иметь его внутри класса
def marry(pers_1, pers_2):
    """Сторонний наблюдатель фиксирует факт того, что два экземпляра поженились"""
    print(f'{pers_1} and {pers_2} got married') # специфичный код
    hypotetic_common_method(pers_1, pers_2)     # вызов общего метода

def hypotetic_common_method(pers_1, pers_2):
    pers_1.isMarriedTo = pers_2
    pers_2.isMarriedTo = pers_1

Bob = Person()
Alice = Person()

Bob.marry(Alice)
marry(Bob, Alice)
```

Comment: Методы класса реализуются через декоратор `@classmethod` и у них первым параметром будет передаваться сам класс: `@classmethod
def marry(cls, pers_1, pers_2):` и вызывать через класс `Person.marry(Bob, Alice)`

Comment: Если я помещаю одноименный "внешний" метод внутрь класса с декоратором '@classmethod', то возникает конфликт имен.
Например, при определении методов в таком порядке:  
'@classmethod def marry(cls, pers_1, pers_2):'  
'def marry(self, other)'  
срабатывает метод экземпляра (видимо потому что определен ниже по коду и переопределяет метод выше)

Не понимаю, в чем разница: при применении декораторов @property и @<property>.setter можно определять одинаковые имена методов, а здесь не получается

Answer (score 1):

Не нужен второй метод `marry`, у вас уже существующий метод может работать через вызов `Person.marry(Bob, Alice)`. При таком вызове `Bob` попадет в параметр `self`, `Alice` - в параметр `other`.

Ну и `hypotetic_common_method` переносите внутрь класса как статический метод, внутри `marry` вызываете его через `Person.hypotetic_common_method(self, other)`.

```
class Person:

    isMarriedTo = None

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    # метод экземпляра
    def marry(self, other):
        """Выбранный Экземпляр (сам) женится на другом экземпляре"""
        print(f'{self} married {other}')     # специфичный код
        Person.hypotetic_common_method(self, other) # вызов общего кода
    
    @staticmethod
    def hypotetic_common_method(pers_1, pers_2):
        pers_1.isMarriedTo = pers_2
        pers_2.isMarriedTo = pers_1


Bob = Person("Bob")
Alice = Person("Alice")

Bob.marry(Alice)
Person.marry(Bob, Alice)
```

Вывод:

```
Bob married Alice
Bob married Alice
```